# How to set a display name for a field in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

Is it possible to set a display name for a database field, instead of using the auto-generated one?

I've got a field `bbe_date`, and in screens, I am using 'Best Before' as the displayed string.  I have been through a few views setting this manually, but is there a better way?

This would hopefully take effect wherever the field name is sent to the browser in human-readable form.  I'm particularly thinking about validation errors as well (since that's the bit I haven't already handled manually!) - my validation code is doing:

```
record.errors.add :bbe_date, 'not valid'
```

but unless I specially intercept this, I just see 'Bbe date not valid' as the validation error.

Comment: Why not refactor the field to be named `best_before`? Just a thought.

Comment: It is a possibility, but I would rather not change the database just because the client wants to see a different name for the field.  And this isn't a general solution, because even the original BBE Date name auto-generates to Bbe date - Rails doesn't know BBE is an acronym.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You need [internationalization (I18N)](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/i18n.html). Yup, even if you just want English.

Modify config/locales/en.yml, and set:

```
en:
  activerecord:
    attributes:
      your_lower_case_model_name:
        bbe_date: Best Before
```

Comment: Sorry about the delay accepting answer!  Just got back to it, and it works great

Answer (score 0):

One way do do this is to override the behavior of `human_attribute_name` which gives you the default display name. In your model:

```
HUMANIZED_ATTRIBUTES = {
  :bbe_date => "Best Before"
}

def self.human_attribute_name(attr, options={})
  HUMANIZED_ATTRIBUTES[attr.to_sym] || super
end
```

Note that if this is Rails 2, you'll need to remove the options param from human_attribute_name.